# How do I make a batch file launch a system command?

Tags: windows-10

I mean by SYSTEM COMMAND an executable routine in Windows that doesn't have an EXE file to back it up, like `CD` or `DEL` or `RMDIR` or `MKDIR` etc.

When I try to call out a file that's not in the path or directory my footprint is in it will run anyway if it's a function built in to the OS. However when I try to put one of those on a line in a batch file the system reports it as not found. It seems batch files must be for things that have an EXE to BAT or MSI or like that to launch.

Actually I really think batch files are smart enough that the way to launch a native OS command is built in and my problem is I just don't know how to invoke it. So, I think the problem is not something Microsoft didn't think of, I think it is missing knowledge on my part. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You NEED to provide an example batch file, pasted from the command prompt, including the error message. And I can almost guarantee that if you write a batch file with one line `CD` it's not going to say "not found" so it's not really clear what yo are talking about. We need to see the batch file, and the exact message you get. And try to include the most simple example you can make that demonstrates your problem

Comment: you can use mkdir C:\newdir. See following link on how to create batch file https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/write-simple-batch-bat-file/

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use those commands in batch files.  It might help to show us what you've come up with which isn't working?

Here's an example of del being used in a batch file:

```
echo Batch to delete file

del "D:\Test_1\Test\*.txt" /s /f /q

echo Done!
```

source: http://www.get-itsolutions.com/create-batch-to-delete-file-cmd/

Answer (score 0):

Those are internal commands of cmd, so just use `cmd /c command` to run from a non-cmd environment (in cmd just run them directly) . For example

```
cnd /c "del mydir" 
cmd /c dir
```

However in case of `cd` the session will end when the command finishes, so the child environment will be destroyed and you won't see the changed folder. Use `cmd /k "cd newdir"` to keep cnd running are the command, although it should be better to set the starting folder for the child cmd another way